# showDialog not showing anything when executed from PopupMenuItem in the AppBar

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an options menu in the AppBar and I need to show dialogs when the buttons are clicked.
Here is my code:

```
    class PricingPage extends StatefulWidget{
    const PricingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

    @override
    _PricingPageState createState() => _PricingPageState();
    }

    class _PricingPageState extends State<PricingPage>  with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Builder(
          builder: (context) => const PricingPageBody(),
        )
      );

    }
  }



  class PricingPageBody extends StatefulWidget {
     const PricingPageBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

     @override
     State<PricingPageBody> createState() => _PricingPageBodyState();
   }


class _PricingPageBodyState extends State<PricingPageBody> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  late TabController _tabController;
  late PageController pageController;
  final backendService = Get.put(PricingController());
  double undercover = 0.0;
  double vip = 0.0;
  double rooftop = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 12, vsync: this, initialIndex: DateTime.now().month - 1)..addListener(() {

    });
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: DateTime.now().month - 1);
    //PricingController().resetAllPrices(22.50, 28.50, 18.50);
  }




@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: const Text('Pricing'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            actions:  [
              Obx(() => 
              Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                child: Row(

                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(backendService.selectedDays.value.toList().length.toString(),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          fontSize: 20
                      ),
                    ),
                    PricingOptionsMenu(
                      selectedDaysLength:backendService.selectedDays.value.toList().length,
                      onUpdateAll: () {

                      }, onDeselectAll: () {

                      backendService.deselectAll();

                    }, onUpdateSelected: () {

                    }, onUpdateMonth: () {
                        WidgetsBinding?.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
                          showDialog(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                              PricingDialog(
                                  dialogTitle: 'Update Prices',
                                  prices: (undercover,vip,rooftop) {
                                    backendService.updateMonth(undercover, vip, rooftop);
                                  })
                          );
                        });

                    },

                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
```

I have searching online for about 2 hours now and most of the solutions i've found suggested that I extract the scaffold widget , wrap in MaterialApp, add a delay before showing the dialog and wrap in `WidgetsBinding?.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {}` but none of those solutions seem to be working.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code (best I can... because of missing widgets) and it not seems to be a problem of the schowDialog method, as it works perfectly...
here the whole code I tried :

```
void main() {
  runApp(const PricingPage());
}

class PricingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PricingPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PricingPageState createState() => _PricingPageState();
}

class _PricingPageState extends State<PricingPage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Builder(
      builder: (context) => const PricingPageBody(),
    ));
  }
}

class PricingPageBody extends StatefulWidget {
  const PricingPageBody({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PricingPageBody> createState() => _PricingPageBodyState();
}

class _PricingPageBodyState extends State<PricingPageBody>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  late PageController pageController;
  // final backendService = Get.put(PricingController());
  double undercover = 0.0;
  double vip = 0.0;
  double rooftop = 0.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(
        length: 12, vsync: this, initialIndex: DateTime.now().month - 1)
      ..addListener(() {});
    pageController = PageController(initialPage: DateTime.now().month - 1);
    //PricingController().resetAllPrices(22.50, 28.50, 18.50);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Pricing'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          actions: [
            Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'some text'
                  ),
                  MaterialButton(child: Text('press me'),
                      onPressed: () {
                    showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) => Center(
                          child: Container(
                                height: 100,
                                width: 100,
                                color: Colors.blue,
                              ),
                        ));
                  })
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

so in my opinion it must be a problem of one of the widgets I couldn't test...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am now able to show the default AboutDialog but when I try to show a custom dialog , after clicking it shows a semi-transparent black overlay without anything else...

Comment: can you add your custom dialog code to your question? the semi-transparent background should appear... but for sure in combination with your widget... so you have to find the problem of your dialog widget...